# creating 12 Hz square signal 50MHz clock signal

Tags: verilog

I wrote code in Verilog that is supposed to create a 12Hz square signal at 50MHz clock signal.
Is it correct?

```
module w_m(clk, cnt); 
input clk; 
output [21:0] cnt; 
reg [21:0] cnt = 0; 
always @(posedge clk) 
cnt = cnt + 1; 
endmodule
```

```
module w_tf;

    reg clk; 

    wire [21:0] cnt; 

    w_m uut 
    ( 
    .clk(clk),
    .cnt(cnt) 
    ); 
    initial begin 
    // Initialize Inputs 
    clk = 0; 
    forever begin 
    #10 
    clk = !clk; 
    end 
    end
    endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it correctly simulates as described, assuming the timescale is set to 1ns.

The `clk` period is 20ns, and its frequency is 50MHz.

The MSB of `cnt` (`cnt[21]`) has a frequency of approximately 12Hz (11.921Hz, according to my simulation results).

You can verifiy this by running a simulation and looking at waveforms.  You can post your code on **edaplayground**, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is right. However, there are some inaccuracies. I have varied the register size in order to run the simulation as allowed by EDA playground.

DUT:

```
module w_m(clk, clk_out); 
input clk; 
//output [21:0] cnt; 
  output clk_out;
  reg [11:0] cnt = 0; // make 11 to 21
always @(posedge clk) 
    cnt = cnt + 1; 

  assign clk_out = cnt[11];

endmodule
```

Also, the testbench needs a $finish to stop the forever block from running infinite, taking up the disk space. Added a parallel path in order to run the sim, and exit after 10000ns. You can vary this as per your need.
TB:

```
module w_tf;

    reg clk; 

    wire  cnt; 

    w_m uut 
    ( 
    .clk(clk),
    .clk_out(cnt) 
    ); 

    initial begin 

    // Initialize Inputs 
    clk = 0; 
      fork
        begin    
          forever begin 
            #10     clk = !clk; end
        end
        begin
          #10000000 $finish; // increase this number as per the simulation requirement
        end
      join

    end
endmodule
```